# Build form by using map(), how to put info from this.state?

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import myPhone from "../service/checkPhone.js";
import {usersParam} from'../variable.js';

class FormForUserChange extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      age: "",
      gender: "",
      phone: "",
      address: "",
      display: "none"
    };
  }
  
  componentWillMount = () => {
    this.setState({ name: this.props.userToChange.name });
    this.setState({ age: this.props.userToChange.age });
    this.setState({ gender: this.props.userToChange.gender });
    this.setState({ phone: this.props.userToChange.phone });
    this.setState({ address: this.props.userToChange.address });
  };

  _makeListFormData=(usersParam)=>{
    return usersParam.map(each => {
      return (
        <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              // defaultValue={this.state.{each}}
              placeholder={each}
              ref={input => (this.each = input)}
            />
      );
    });
  }
  _handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ gender: event.target.value });
  };
  _handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (
      this.name.value &&
      this.address.value &&
      this.phone.value &&
      this.age.value &&
      myPhone(this.phone.value)
    ) {
      const changedUser = {
        name: this.name.value,
        age: this.age.value,
        gender: this.state.gender,
        phone: this.phone.value,
        address: this.address.value,
        id: this.props.userToChange.ident
      };
      this.props.saveChangedUser(changedUser, this.props.userToChange.hash);
    } else {
      this.setState({ display: "block" });
    }
  };

  render() {
    let form;
    let btnText;
    const styles = {
      display: this.state.display
    };
    const inputsInForm=this._makeListFormData(usersParam);
    if (this.props.openModal) {
      form = (
        <div className="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" id="form">
          <form
            className="form-control-file. form-container"
            onSubmit={this._handleSubmit.bind(this)}
          >
            {inputsInForm}
            <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
              Save changes
            </button>
          </form>
          <span id="form-fill-error" style={styles}>
            please fill out all fields correct
          </span>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      form = "";
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary"
          id="add-user-btn"
          disabled="disabled"
        >
          {btnText}
        </button>
        {form}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FormForUserChange;
```

I have an array from which I build inputs for form(_makeListFormData). In phraseholder  I have to put info from state(which comes from props).

So in placeholder I should put something like this.state{each} it does't work off course. Can you give me an advise how to make it?

Comment: It is not very clear what you want. How is your `usersParam` shape? Also, can you show us other parts of your component? Especially how and where do you use `_makeListFormData` function.

Comment: I put entire component. Can you watch?

Comment: `usersParam`? And what exactly do you want to put your placeholder from this array?

Comment: I want to put not from this array - from state. name, age, gender, etc. It depends on each from array - the same param I have in State. It is previous value, which can be changed in this form.  So it could look like this this.state{each}. But it doesn't work in such way

Comment: Ok, but I need to see `usersParam`. Are there any default keys? So, you want to match those keys with your state properties?

Comment: export const usersParam=['name', 'age', 'gender', 'phone', 'address']; yes they match with my state properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `placeholder={this.state[each]}` for your situation. Also, use `componentDidMount` since `componentWillMount` will be deprecated in the future as @Think-Twice explained. Also, set your state in one time, not separately like that.

```js
const usersParam = ['name', 'age', 'gender', 'phone', 'address'];

class FormForUserChange extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      age: "",
      gender: "",
      phone: "",
      address: "",
      display: "none"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({
      name: this.props.userToChange.name,
      age: this.props.userToChange.age,
      gender: this.props.userToChange.gender,
      phone: this.props.userToChange.phone,
      address: this.props.userToChange.address,
    });
  };

  _makeListFormData = (usersParam) => {
    return usersParam.map(each => {
      return (
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type="text"
          // defaultValue={this.state.{each}}
          placeholder={this.state[each]}
          ref={input => (this.each = input)}
        />
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    const inputsInForm = this._makeListFormData(usersParam);
    return(
      <div>{inputsInForm}</div>
    );
  }
}

const userToChange = {
  name: "foo",
  age: 25,
  gender: "male",
  phone: "123",
  address: "some add",
}

ReactDOM.render(<FormForUserChange userToChange={userToChange} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me. this.state[each] - I was looking for it!

Comment: You are welcome. You better look at getting values from an object by using a variable :)

Comment: Learning things from your answers @devserkan in few questions where we both are answering :)

Comment: Ok will again meet tomorrow. Until then bye 

Answer (score 0):

This is not solution for your issue though but few issues I would like to address.

Stop using componentWillMount because this is deprecated.

so you can directly assign props in constructor

```
  constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
            name: this.props.userToChange.name,
            age: this.props.userToChange.age,
            gender: this.props.userToChange.gender,
            phone: this.props.userToChange..phone,
            address: this.props.userToChange.address,
            display: "none"
       };
   }
```

Note: you no need to use setState for each. You can do everything thing in single setState like below

```
     this.setState({
            name: this.props.userToChange.name,
            age: this.props.userToChange.age,
            gender: this.props.userToChange.gender,
            phone: this.props.userToChange..phone,
            address: this.props.userToChange.address,
            display: "none"
       });
```

Comment: ok. thanks. but everyone said me that I should use ComponentWillMount....

Comment: componentWillMount is deprecated and will be removed in future. Whatever you are doing in componentWillMount can be moved to constructor because both constructor and componentWillMount gets called before first render. So moving it to constructor makes sense interms of initialising state with props values